# Реализовать диалоги: показывать последние сообщения сверху

Tags: php

Реализовал отправку сообщений пользователям. В общем возможность открытия диалога переписки, всё сделал, чтобы уведомлялось о новых сообщениях и т.п. Но одна проблема: если у пользователя много друзей, ему придётся искать от кого сообщения. Как сделать, чтобы этот диалог появлялся вверху? Становился на первое место? Ну типа страницу "последние диалоги".. Можно просто схему написать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгого сеанса воображения я понял, что имеется ввиду.

```
SELECT messages FROM table_name ORDER BY status ASC
```

Или `DESC` вместо `ASC` - это смотря, каким числом помечаются прочитанные сообщения. Если `0`, то `DESC`, чтобы те, у которых 1 были сверху по списку.

Comment: Нужно отсортировать, сперва по статусу, а потом по дате.